# Highlight the Html Table using Hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

I use the following code for create table with Three Rows.First and third row Contains the data.But the second row Can,t have the data itself.I use the hover method the Rows can be selected properly.But i no need to select the Empty Row.That means if i **mouseover the empty row it will also selected.How to prevent the highlight Empty rows**?

Table Creation:

```
 <table id="asdf">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem</td> <td>Ipsum</td> <td>Fierent</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td style="height:10px" colspan=3></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td >mnesarchum ne </td> <td >sapientem</td> <td >fierent mnesarchum </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
```

Jquery For call hovered:

```
    $('#asdf tr').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('hovered');
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hovered');
    });
```

Mouse over method:

```
   .hovered td {
        background: #ddd;
    }
```

[Click Here for Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c9h5w/13/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your 'empty' row using .text()

```
$('#asdf tr').mouseover(function() {
    if($.trim($(this).text()) != '')
       $(this).addClass('hovered');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hy93J/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#asdf tr:not(:empty)').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

Comment: If i use like this still the empty row selected ..check http://jsfiddle.net/c9h5w/14/

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to add a class onto the rows that have data and do this:

```
$('#asdf tr.has-data').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS approach (with no jQuery event binding)

```
$('#asdf tr').each(function(){
 if($.trim($(this).text()) == ''){
   $(this).addClass('hover-disabled');
 }
});

tr{ background-color: #FFF;}
tr:hover{ background-color: #AAA;}

tr.hover-disabled:hover{background-color: #FFF;}
//Must be defined in that order
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$('#asdf tr:first,#asdf tr:last').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#asdf tr:has(td:not(:empty))').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c9h5w/15/)

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you can prevent the highlight empty rows

```
$('#asdf tr').mouseover(function() {
        if (!$.trim($(this).text()))$(this).removeClass('hovered')
        else $(this).addClass('hovered');   
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hovered');
    });
```